# Cache asynchronous function result in C#

Tags: c#, caching, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am reading the asynchronous function section in "C# in a Nutshell". One example is as follow:

Suppose we need to handle a 'Download' button click event and we want to cache the download results. If we don't care about downloading the **same** website in case the button is clicked repeatedly then it's eaiser.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string uri)
    {
        string content;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(uri, out content)) return content;
        return _cache[uri] = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    }
```

But this means it will issue redundant downloads to the same website if, for example, it's clicked twice in a row! To protect this, the book suggests caching `Task<string>` instead.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Task<string>> _futureCache = new Dictionary<string, Task<string>>();
Task<string> GetWebPage(string uri)
    {
        lock (_futureCache)
        {
            Task<string> task;
            if (_futureCache.TryGetValue(uri, out task)) return task; 
            return _futureCache[uri] = new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
        }
    }
```

But I don't understand how this protection can be effective. I assume the click event handler would be something like this:

```
 _downloadBtn.Click += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            var uri = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"; // for argument sake, it always downloads bbc...
            string result = await GetWebPage(uri);
            // process the result...
        };
```

If, for some reason, the download triggered by the first click is still in process and then the button is clicked for a 2nd time; isn't it going to still download the page twice since the cache hasn't yet be populated from the 1st download by the time a 2nd click is fired? If my understanding is wrong, please explain why. Otherwise, how to implement such a cache protecing repeated user click?

By the way, I understand that the cache works effectively if it's used outside the event handler (UI) context e.g. below it only downloads once.

```
    async void Foo()
    {
        var uri = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";
        string result;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //Stimulate repeated call
        {
            result = await GetWebPage(uri); 
            Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That code works fine. Hint: there's no `await` in `GetWebPage` :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it's deliberately having no await to instigate concurrency!

Comment: Exactly, the code won't add a second task when there's already a task in progress (or if it's already completed for that matter) :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski got what you meant now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_futureCache` dictionary is caching a `Task` based on a `uri` key.  It is preventing you from creating a new `Task` when asking for the web page, and instead will return the `Task` that was already created last time that `uri` was request-- whether or not that `Task` has completed.  Then the calling code awaits the same `Task` for every request to that `uri`.  If already completed, it returns immediately with the result of that `Task`.  If not, it waits until it is finished.  No matter what, it will only fetch the page once.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you but when the 1st call to a uri and there is no cache, it'll request a download, while this download is in progress, are you saying the cache is populated already to an ongoing task?

Comment: `GetWebPage` is not marked `async`.  It returns a task, but doesn't wait for it to complete.  So it goes in the cache while the Monitor lock on `_futureCache` is held to prevent race conditions.  The second request would block there for a few nanoseconds until the Task was *started* and added to the cache.

Comment: Ok think that means the same thing as my first comment e.g as soon as the first task is started, even though it's still ongoing it's cached already. So the second request might get an incomplete task from the cache but still won't trigger another request/task?